# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pluginObj._objectInstance') IONIC 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Soo usually when I see a message like this the object inside the quotes is usually an object i coded. But in this case I'm not too familiar with pluginObj._objectInstance is for so debugging this is quite difficult. I looked online and couldn't find anything on it except the actual source code which doesn't tell me jack since I'm still new.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pluginObj._objectInstance')
```

I'm working with ionic 2 and grabbing data from sqlite if that helps. The error shows up on xcode

Comment: Can you share part of the code with error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a creppy solution by that issue, it is still working in Android and iOS

The documentation says: 
Execute SQL on the opened database. Note, you must call openDatabase first, and ensure it resolved and successfully opened the database.

By some reason the database don't is open succesfully, so try to open again

```
public database: SQLite;

this.database = new SQLite();

this.database.openDatabase({name: "data.db", location: "default"}).then(() => {

this.database.executeSql('Insert statement', []).then((data) => {

}, (error) => {
    console.log("ERROR insert: " + error);
});
}, (error) => {
console.log("ERROR open database: ", error);
});
```

Mean while i spend the final answer in thre ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sqlite-cant-executesql/66575/8

Comment: I found the solution a while back ago. I don't remember the properties exactly but If i were to print out the obj. It would show up as something like this {prop1: " ":, pro2: " "} on the console in xcode. But it wasn't empty when I was testing it on the web. So I just went into the object anyway even though it say it was empty. Soo weird right? I love Hybrid! lmfaoo soooo easy to debug